# Play 2.0 controller concurrent access and remove same record

Tags: concurrency, playframework, playframework-2.0

In play 2.x application, I have a post request that is used to remove a child member from parent table. If there are multiple requests with same requesting parameters, how could I ask Play to lock the children list to avoid concurrent access and duplicate removal of same record? If duplicate requests are sent very closely, an exception is thrown like below:

> javax.persistence.OptimisticLockException: Data has changed. updated
>   [0] rows sql[delete from channel_detail where id=? and
>   member_id=? and channel_info_id=?] bind[null]

```
@BodyParser.Of(BodyParser.FormUrlEncoded.class)
public static Result removeMemberFromChannel() {
    RequestBody body = request().body();
    Map<String, String[]> dict = body.asFormUrlEncoded();
    final String memberId = dict.get("memberId") != null ? dict.get(Config.MEMBER_ID_PARAM)[0] : null;

    ChannelInfo channelInfo = ChannelInfo.getChannelForName(channelName); //method was removed to save space
    if (channelInfo != null) {
       channelInfo.removeMemberId(memberId);
       channelInfo.save();
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="channel")
public class ChannelInfo extends Model {
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    private String channelName;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy="channelInfo")
    private Set<ChannelDetailMember> members;

    private int membersCount = 0;

    public void removeMemberId(String memberId) {
        Iterator<ChannelDetailMember> iter = this.getMembers().iterator();
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            ChannelDetailMember dMember = iter.next();
            if (dMember.getMemberId().equals(memberId)) {
               dMember.delete();
               membersCount--;
               break;
            }
         }
    }
}

@Entity
@Table(name="channel_detail")
public class ChannelDetailMember extends Model {

    @Id
    private Long id;

    @Constraints.Required
    private String memberId;

    @Constraints.Required
    @ManyToOne(cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
    ChannelInfo channelInfo;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether Play itself comes with a mechanism to prevent something like this to happen, and the exception that is thrown is already one form of locking strategy. I think the main issue is that the data has the time to change between when you fetch it and when you want to delete the entry, so it'd do one of the following:

- implement the removal method differently, so that both lookup and removal of the member happen in one go (disclaimer: I'm not well-acquainted with EBean so I'm not sure at all about how it deals with transaction management)
- catch the `OptimisticLockException`, then try the deletion again after a few seconds and repeat e.g. 3 times if it fails again the same way